# How to call API using POST or PUT

Tags: php, api, laravel-4

I need to call API through HTTP request with custom headers and custom HTTP verb

```
PUT: http://www.example.com/system/get_user_categories/format/json/user_id/**10**
```

I guess I need to use:

```
request::create
```

But I don't know how.

Comment: http://www.antoine-augusti.fr/blog/2014/04/laravel-calling-your-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task you can use "Guzzle" PHP-HTTP-Client.

To send requests GET,POST,PUT,DELETE ...

http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/http-messages.html#requests

http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#sending-requests

For custom headers see:

http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/http-messages.html#headers

Guzzle is powerfull and easy to use AND there are a lot of "copy-paste" examples you can try out :)

---

Symfony2 Guzzle composer-package:

https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: always receive [status code] 401 [reason phrase] Authorization Required

Comment: how to send .htaccess username and password in Guzzle request

Answer (score 0):

Laravel’s request object simply extends Symfony’s HTTP request class (and adds a few Laravel-specific methods), so anything you could do with `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` you can do with Laravel’s request class.

You’re right in that you can use `Request::create()`. See this section in the Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#simulating-a-request

Comment: I tried use symfony: Request::create() but json reposen not returned?